# Create Object Using Constructor and Argument with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a scenario where I want to create an object (`Calc`) which takes some options as a constructor argument. It happens I have a serialized version of `Calc`, its properties and the options properties as another single object. Here's my code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
    {
        c.AddProfile<MapperProf>();
    })
    .CreateMapper();
}

public class MapperProf : Profile
{
    public MapperProf()
    {
        CreateMap<Scen, Calc>()
            .ConstructUsing(c => new Calc())  // I AM STUCK HERE
            
            
        CreateMap<Scen, Opt>()
            .ForMember(o => o.OptProp, o => o.MapFrom(o => o.OptProp));
    }
}

public class Calc
{
    public Calc(Opt opt)
    {
        OptProp = opt.OptProp;
    }
    
    public string CalcProp { get; set; }
    
    private string OptProp { get; set; }
}

public class Opt
{
    
    
    public string OptProp { get; set; }
}

public class Scen
{
    public string CalcProp { get; set; }
    public string OptProp { get; set; }
}
```

For various reasons I cannot access `Calc.OptProp`, I have to pass it in via the constructor argument.

In equivalent terms what I want to do in one shot is:

```cs
Calc c = mockMapper.Map<Calc>().ConstructUsing(c => new Calc(mockMapper.Map<Opt>(scen)));
```

That is, construct both the `Calc` and `Opt` from the same `Scen`.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ConstructUsing` you can use `ResulotionContext` and then use mapper for create constructor like this:

```
public class MapperProf : Profile
{
   public MapperProf()
   {
    CreateMap<Scen, Opt>().ForMember(o => o.OptProp, o => o.MapFrom(scen => scen.OptProp));

    CreateMap<Scen, Calc>().ConstructUsing((scen, context) => new Calc(context.Mapper.Map<Scen, Opt>(scen)));
   }
};
```

And for mapping scen:

```cs
var scen = new Scen() { CalcProp = "Calc", OptProp = "Opt" };

var calc = mockMapper.Map<Scen, Calc>(scen);
```

Comment: Thanks @Saeed Esmaeelinejad. Following your answer I also discovered that `CreateMap<Scen, Calc>().ConstructUsing(c => new Calc(new Opt()));` works as long as the `Calc.OptProp` property is `public get, private set`.

Comment: @phil Yes you can use ``new Opt()`` but be aware maybe later some properties add to ``Opt`` and map to different property of ``Calc``, so it's better use ``new Calc(context.Mapper.Map<Scen, Opt>(scen))``